# Perform Segue from Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

```
import UIKit

class ActionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var actionGIF: UIImageView!

     @IBAction func actionPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         print(myLabel.text)
         Global.actionButtonIndex = myLabel.text!.toInt()! - 1
         print(actionGIF.image)
         ActionViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("showActionPreview", sender: nil)
}
```

}

I am trying to perform a Segue after User Clicking on One of the Cell in my Collection View. Can't seem to do that using performSegueWithIdentifier. [App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQYvy.png)

Comment: You haven't described the problem. Is it crashing? What is `ActionViewController`? Is it a class or instance?

Comment: Use the collectionView(didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) method specified in the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol rather than an action within your cell, unless you need multiple buttons per cell with different actions.

Comment: Did You Solve it? Im having the same issue, Did select item don't work for me, since I have the Cell + a button inside the cell, the button, does something different from pressing the cell.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an elegant solution that only requires a few lines of code:

1. Create a custom UICollectionViewCell subclass
2. Using storyboards, define an IBAction for the "*Touch Up Inside*" event of your button
3. Define a closure
4. Call the closure from the IBAction

**Swift 4+** code

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        static let reuseIdentifier = "MyCustomCell"

        @IBAction func onAddToCartPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            addButtonTapAction?()
        }

        var addButtonTapAction : (()->())?
    }
```

Next, implement the logic you want to execute inside the closure in your

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
        }

        // Configure the cell
        // ...


        cell.addButtonTapAction = {
            // implement your logic here, e.g. call preformSegue()  
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your segue", sender: self)              
        }

        return cell
    }
```

You can use this approach also with table view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

**Instance method `performSegue` is not available from a `UICollectionViewCell`:**

Since an `UICollectionViewCell` is not an `UIViewController`, you can not use [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) from it. You may prefer use delegates to notify your parent view controller and then, `performSegue` from there.

Take a look at the details of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457583/1352748). The question is slightly different but the solution lies in the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the segue identifier by exactly named "showActionPreview". Moreover, ensure that your segue linked from your parent view controller to your destination view controller in storyboard. Hope this would be help.