# Perform Segue from UICollectionViewCell Button different from Cell Click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell`, with a `UIButton`. And I have two different actions. The first one, when the user presses the cell, it will segue to another view with`didSelectITemAt`; the second one, when the users presses the `UIButton` inside the cell.
My problem is that on Swift Code of `MyCollectionViewCell`, I cant perform a segue, When I write the Code:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toStoreFromMyDiscounts", sender: nil)
```

it says the error:

> Value of Type MyCollectionViewCell has no member performSegue.

I also cannot write `prepareForSegue`, it doesn't auto complete.

How can I create a segue from a cell, that is different from click the cell itself?

Comment: Have you thought about using a delegate?

Comment: so you are trying to segue from the cell, as well as from the button inside the cell? which one is not working?

Comment: I want both, and I want them to go to different places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not call `performSegue` from your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, because there is [no interface declared](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell)  on `UICollectionViewCell` like that.

The reason why it is working `didSelectItemAtIndexPath()` is because i suppose the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate?language=objc) of your `UICollectionView` is a `UIViewController` subclass, what has the function called [performSegueWithIdentifier:()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performseguewithidentifier).

You need to notify your `UIViewController` when the button was clicked in your `UICollectionViewCell`, for what you have various possibilities, like KVO or using delegate.

Here is a little code sniplet, how to use KVO. This solution is great, as long as you do not care, in which cell was the button pressed.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        // Add your `UIViewController` subclass, `CollectionViewController`, as the target of the button
        // Check out the documentation of addTarget(:) https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTappedInCollectionViewCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func buttonTappedInCollectionViewCell(sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toStoreFromMyDiscounts", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you care, in which cell the touch event has happend, use the delegate pattern.

```
import UIKit

protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
    // Declare a delegate function holding a reference to `UICollectionViewCell` instance
    func collectionViewCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, buttonTapped: UIButton)
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    // Add a delegate property to your UICollectionViewCell subclass
    weak var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        // Add the resposibility of detecting the button touch to the cell, and call the delegate when it is tapped adding `self` as the `UICollectionViewCell`
        self.delegate?.collectionViewCell(self, buttonTapped: button)
    }
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        // Asssign the delegate to the viewController
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

// Make `CollectionViewController` confrom to the delegate 
extension CollectionViewController: CollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func collectionViewCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, buttonTapped: UIButton) {
        // You have the cell where the touch event happend, you can get the indexPath like the below 
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        // Call `performSegue`
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toStoreFromMyDiscounts", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I Do care witch cell was tapped, how can I do it with that?

Comment: Thanks, Will try it now!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an elegant solution that only requires a few lines of code:

1. Create a custom UICollectionViewCell subclass
2. Using storyboards, define an IBAction for the "*Touch Up Inside*" event of your button
3. Define a closure
4. Call the closure from the IBAction

**Swift 4+** code

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        static let reuseIdentifier = "MyCustomCell"

        @IBAction func onAddToCartPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            addButtonTapAction?()
        }

        var addButtonTapAction : (()->())?
    }
```

Next, implement the logic you want to execute inside the closure in your

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
        }

        // Configure the cell
        // ...


        cell.addButtonTapAction = {
            // implement your logic here, e.g. call preformSegue()  
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your segue", sender: self)              
        }

        return cell
    }
```

You can use this approach also with table view controllers.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that also works like a charm:

```
extension YOURViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YOURCell", for: indexPath) as! YOURCollectionViewCell

         cell.butTapped = {
             [weak self] (YOURCollectionViewCell) -> Void in
             // do your actions when button tapped
         }
    }        
    return cell
}


class YOURCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
     var butQRTapped: ((YOURCollectionViewCell) -> Void)?
     @IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         butTapped?(self)
     }
}
```